# How to assemble many projects into a single?(qml/qt)

Tags: qt, qml

I have 4 projects. Everyone has its own additional qml files. I need to assemble them as one.

How can i do it?

This is projects.

[image]

This is an example of what the project file system looks like.

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for `subdirs`, check this wiki: https://wiki.qt.io/SUBDIRS_-_handling_dependencies

Comment: Like @Amfasis has mentioned, subdirs is the way to go. If you're using git, I highly recommend putting your reusable components in a `git submodule`. Then, project can consume and contribute to the common repo. I have an example of this with https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-toolkit which is used in both https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-promises-demo and https://github.com/stephenquan/qmlonline6